# Python: Keyword to Links

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I am building a blog on Google App Engine. I would like to convert some keywords in my blog posts to links, just like what you see in many WordPress blogs.

Here is one WP plugin which do the same thing:http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blog-mechanics-keyword-link-plugin-v01/

A plugin that allows you to define keyword/link pairs. The keywords are automatically linked in each of your posts.

I think this is more than a simple Python Replace. What I am dealing with is HTML code. It can be quite complex sometimes.

Take the following code snippet as an example. I want to conver the word `example` into a link to `http://example.com`:

```
Here is an example link:<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
```

By a simple Python replace function which replaces `example` with `<a href="http://example.com">example</a>`, it would output:

```
Here is an <a href="http://example.com">example</a> link:<a href="http://<a href="http://example.com">example</a>.com"><a href="http://example.com">example</a>.com</a>
```

but I want:

```
Here is an <a href="http://example.com">example</a> link:<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
```

Is there any Python plugin that capable of this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: "a simple Python replace function" - show us your code.

Comment: @Roman Er, `my_string.replace(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is roughly what you could do using [Beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html_body ="""
Here is an example link:<a href='http://example.com'>example.com</a>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_body)
for link_tag in soup.findAll('a'):
    link_tag.string = "%s%s%s" % ('|',link_tag.string,'|')
for text in soup.findAll(text=True):
    text_formatted = ['<a href=""http://example.com"">example</a>'\ 
    if word == 'example' and not (word.startswith('|') and word.endswith('|'))\
    else word for word in foo.split() ]
    text.replaceWith(' '.join(text_formatted))
for link_tag in soup.findAll('a'):
    link_tag.string = link_tag.string[1:-1]
print soup
```

Basically I'm stripping out all the text from the `post_body`, replacing the example word with the given link, without touching the links text that are saved by the '|' characters during the parsing.

This is not 100% perfect, for example it does not work if the word you are trying to replace ends with a period; with some patience you could fix all the edge cases.

Comment: Thanks. AFAIK, BeautifulSoup is not only slow but also choking on malformed HTML. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Doc it is slow, but since you are on a constrained environment like Google App Engine, you are forced to adopt something purely in Python. Without this constrain, lxml is the preferred library.

Comment: eeeeeeeew. (@ using | symbols to delimit links).

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be better suited to client-side code. You could easily modify a [word highlighter](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript+hilight+words#hl=en&sa=X&ei=vbwqTpCPKYyv8QOE68CcDA&ved=0CBoQvwUoAQ&q=javascript+highlight+words&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=332aa4b9e1a99547&biw=1157&bih=983) to get the desired results. By keeping this client-side, you can avoid having to expire page caches when your 'tags' change.

If you really need it to be processed server-side, then you need to look at using [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) which lets you pass in a function, but unless you are operating on plain-text you will have to first parse the HTML using something like [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) to ensure you are not replacing something in the middle of any elements.